# Web Scraping: Some Pages URL are missing

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to scrap the first 9 pages of a website but it looks like page5 and page7 are missing. This is making show python an attribute error. However, I think an 'if' function can solve this but I'm unable to figure out the code for the if function. 
Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url="http://cbcs.fastvturesults.com/student/1sp15me00"
for page in range(1,10,1):
    r=requests.get(base_url+str(page))
    c=r.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    items=soup.find(class_="text-muted")
    if ??????????:
        pass
    else:
        print("{}\n{}".format(items.previous_sibling,items.text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `else` block here. Only checking `if items is not None` suffices. Try the below approach:

```
items = soup.find(class_="text-muted")
if items:
    print("{}\n{}".format(items.previous_sibling,items.text))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs when you try to access attributes of `items` when `items` is set to `None`. This is done when BeautifulSoup cannot find anything with `class_="text-muted"`

**The solution:**

```
if not items:
    continue
```

Note that `pass`(from your solution) will just pass the current statement and move on to the next line in the loop. `continue` will end the current iteration and move on to the next iteration.